# Оформление диплома в LaTex

Tags: latex

При конвертации в pdf появляется ошибка

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6630)
>
> entering extended mode
>
> (_DIPLOMA.tex
>
> ! Undefined control sequence. l.6 \documentclass
>
> ```
>               [a4paper, 14pt]{extarticle} ?
> ```

Способы исправления у нее есть?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70381/the-article-class-ignores-14pt

Comment: А Вы точно используете компилятор `pdflatex`? А не `pdftex`? Такая ошибка будет только у `pdftex` - он не знает, что такое класс документа.

Comment: @Vladimir, в pdflatex ошибка та же была,  не было базы extsizes